# Solve inequality involving double summation, exponentiation and $\ln$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, exponential-function, exponential-sum, summation-method

I have the following inequality (where $n$ is a real number):

$$\sum_{a=1}^n\sum_{b=1}^n\frac{a^n}{n^2}e^{-n-ba}\ge\ln n$$

Computation suggests this holds for $n$ greater than or equal to a number somewhere between $10.75$ and $11$. But can I solve the inequality algebraically? And if so, how?

UPDATE:

I realise that $n$ is strictly speaking only defined for integer values, but rather than just say that the inequality is satisfied (by direct computation) for $n\ge11$, I want to understand the process of solving such an inequality algebraically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

\begin{align}
\sum_{a=1}^n\sum_{b=1}^n\frac{a^n}{n^2}e^{-n-ba}
&=\frac{e^{-n}}{n^2}\sum_{a=1}^n \left(a^n \sum_{b=1}^n  (e^{-a})^b\right)\\
&=\frac{e^{-n}}{n^2}\sum_{a=1}^n \dfrac{a^ne^{-a}(e^{-na}-1)}{e^{-a}-1}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Hi @Karn Watcharasupat, thank you for this. This is really useful, but I don't see what I would do next...?