# Inequality involving double summation

Tags: inequality, summation, exponential-function, exponential-sum, summation-method

I have the inequality

$$e^{-10}\sum_{a=0}^{n-i}a\sum_{b=0}^{n-1}e^{-abn(a-2bn)}<\ln n$$

A table in Mathematica quickly shows that the largest integer $n$ for which the inequality holds is $n=2$. But sadly Mathematica isn't smart enough to Solve the inequality explicitly.

Can someone suggest what steps I might take to solve it algebraically - i.e., to derive an algebraic condition on $n$ for which the inequality holds?

(Note that this similar to a question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3311322/solve-inequality-involving-double-summation-exponentiation-and-ln) - but this inequality is much harder because $-abn(a-2bn)$ is irreducible.)

P.S.: Here is the Mathematica code in case anyone finds it useful:

```
TableForm[Quiet[Table[
{n, 
 N[Sum[a*Sum[E^((-a)*b*n*
        (a - 2*b*n)), {b, 0, 
       n - 1}], {a, 0, n - 1}]/
   E^11], N[Log[n]]}, {n, 0, 5}]], 
TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "function", "Log[n]"}}]
```

Comment: Transcendental equation(inequality) can't be solved algebraically. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation

Comment: Hi @Mariusz Iwaniuk. I take your point. However, it's also clear that *bounds* on the behaviour of many famous transcendental functions *have* been found algebraically (to choose a super-simple example, the behaviour of $\ln n$ in relation to $H(n)$). So I guess my question is, is it possible to even narrow things down algebraically for this particular function?

Comment: Maybe this helps,MMA code:`EvenInteger = 12(* Try increase.Only even Integers *); func = 
 Sum[(Series[
     1/Exp[10]*a E^((-a)*b*n*(a - 2*b*n)), {n, 0, EvenInteger}] // 
    Normal), {b, 0, n - 1}, {a, 0, n - 1}]; Reduce[func < Log[n], n]`

Comment: Thank you. What does the slot stand for in this particular case? I assume it's indicating the same thing as $n$...? In which case, I can totally see that I'm on a hiding to nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $i$ in the upper bound for the sum is a misprint and there should be $1$ instead. Then the inequality fails for any $n\ge 3$, because in this case a summand with $a=b=n-1$ of the left hand side equals 
$$ae^{-abn(a-2bn)-10}=(n-1)e^{(n-1)^3n(2n-1)-10}\ge e^n\ge n\ge \ln n.$$